# React native [TypeError: Network request failed]

Tags: javascript, android, ios, facebook, react-native

I'm just trying to run the example fetch from the RN docs calling out to http://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json. When I try it out on the simulator its fine. But when I plug in my device and and deploy it to that using react-native run-android it can't seem to successfully load the data.

it's giving an error

> [TypeError: Network request failed]

Comment: Would need to see some code, but it's most probably due to calling the wrong URI. The request working on an emulator but not on a physical device would indicate that you are maybe calling something like `localhost`, which simply doesn't resolve correctly on the physical device you're using.